# Cannot select file

Tags: angular

I am using the [ngx-input-file](https://github.com/rsaenen/ngx-input-file) component to upload files. When I select a file, it is not selected, the following message is displayed in the console:

```
> console.log(this.selectedFiles)
FileList {length: 0}
```

This problem only occurs when using this component.

If to do so:

```
<input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
```

everything is working fine.

How else can  select a file?

html:

```
<input-file  fileLimit="1" (change)="selectFile($event)"  sizeLimit="2" [linkEnabled]="true"
 placeholder="File" placeholderLink="File link"></input-file>
```

ts:

```
  selectedFiles: FileList;

  selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    console.log(this.selectedFiles)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to get the file's data/attributes, you can use `ngModel`, or reactive forms, to store the file.

If you are using template-driven forms, or `ngModel`, you can bind `ngModel` to a property (`uploadedFile`), and use bind the `selectFile()` method to `ngModelChange`.

```
<input-file  fileLimit="1" [(ngModel)]="uploadedFile" (ngModelChange)="selectFile()" sizeLimit="2" [linkEnabled]="true"
 placeholder="File" placeholderLink="File link"></input-file>
```

On the component.ts,

```
uploadedFile: UploadedFile[];

selectFile() {
  if (this.uploadedFile && this.uploadedFile.length > 0) {
    console.log(this.uploadedFile[0].file)
  }
}
```

I would also recommend you to create an interface for the uploadedFile property.

```
interface UploadedFile {
  file: File;
}
```

You may refer to the demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file-k7zepz?file=src/app/app.component.html). Do note that if you want to view the full `console.log()` printout of the file, you will have to rely on your browser's inspect element console tool, as Stackblitz's console does not print the full response.